# Apache2 2.4 ignoring my default config

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, apache-2.4

Ok so i have installed apache2 2.4 and i am having problems with porting my old wesites/configs across from old server (apache 2.2) to new one.

By default apache 2.4 default web dir is /var/www/html but this can/should be overriden via /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf file.

my 000-default.conf files:

```
<VirtualHost extern1:80>
        HostnameLookups Off
        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_log
        TransferLog /var/log/apache2/access_log

        <Directory "/var/www/">
                allow from all
                AllowOverride all
                Options +Indexes
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

inside my www folder there is

```
- html folder
- index.php (with phpinfo());
```

However after setting this up, after apache reload, when i access my ip it still opens the default 'debian' webpage and NOT the `index.php` file as per `000-default.config`

Does any one know what else needs to be done ?

Comment: Try running `apachectl -S` to dump the running config.  Is the virtual host that is  actually used coming from the config file you expect?

Comment: @Zoredache handy command - it turned out that 'extern1' was not recognized so this config was not actually working - changed to *:80 and it works :)